# Is the PySide Slot Decorator Necessary?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

I've seen some example code for PySide slots that uses the @QtCore.Slot decorator, and some that does not.  Testing it myself, it doesn't seem to make a difference.  Is there a reason I should or should not use it?  For example, in the following code:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore

# the next line seems to make no difference
@QtCore.Slot()
def a_slot(s):
    print s

class SomeClass(QtCore.QObject):
    happened = QtCore.Signal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
    def do_signal(self):
        self.happened.emit("Hi.")

sc = SomeClass()
sc.happened.connect(a_slot)
sc.do_signal()
```

the @QtCore.Slot decorator makes no difference; I can omit it, call @QtCore.Slot(str), or even @QtCore.Slot(int), and it still nicely says, "Hi."

The same seems to be true for PyQt's pyqtSlot.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[This](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) link explains the following about the `pyqtSlot` decorator:

> Although PyQt4 allows any Python callable to be used as a slot when
>   connecting signals, it is sometimes necessary to explicitly mark a
>   Python method as being a Qt slot and to provide a C++ signature for
>   it. PyQt4 provides the pyqtSlot() function decorator to do this.

and

> Connecting a signal to a decorated Python method also has the
>   advantage of reducing the amount of memory used and is slightly
>   faster.

Since the `pyqtSlot` decorator can take additional argument such as `name`, it allows different Python methods to handle the different signatures of a signal.

If you don't use the slot decorator, the signal connection mechanism has to manually work out all the type conversions to map from the underlying C++ function signatures to the Python functions.  When the slot decorators are used, the type mapping can be explicit.

Comment: Thank you for that concise and complete answer.  I've been relying mostly on the PySide documents, since that's the library I'm using, but I see the advantage of sorting through the PyQt ones.

Comment: I don't entirely understand this answer -- if I'm defining my own slot (or overriding a built-in one for that matter), why would I need a C++ function signature (there's no C++ function...)?

Comment: @simon Qt is implemented in C++ along with the signals/slots mechanism so at some point, even if you define your own signals/slots they will traverse the underlying C++ implementation.

Comment: @AustinPhillips what differentiates a Qt slot from a non-Qt slot in Pyside? I am never sure what that means. Also, do we really provide C++ signatures in PySide when using the new-style signals and slots (as Jason does in his example above)? Also I have a slot that uses 'sender' and when I try to put `@QtCore.Slot()` before the definition, the slot doesn't work. So it doesn't seem universally true that adding the decorator is a Good Thing.

Comment: Just found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015684/pyside-qtcore-slot-decorator-does-not-work-with-self-sender-inside-a-method

Comment: * it is sometimes necessary to explicitly mark a Python method as being a Qt slot*. I wonder what those *sometimes* are, it seems the document writer did not know. For example if I use QThread is it mandatory? if not then when.

Comment: @dashesy It's necessary when you want to have different Python methods handle different signatures of the signal, per the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 13):

Austin has a good answer, and the answer I'm about to write is a bit outside the scope of your question, but it's something that has been confusing me and I imagine others will end up on this page wondering the same thing.

*If you want to expose Python methods to JavaScript (using QTWebKit)*, then the `@pyqtSlot` decorator is mandatory. Undecorated methods are not exposed to JavaScript.

Comment: Well, this is a better answer at least it tells us when it is mandatory.

Comment: @QtCore.Slot() for pyside2

Answer (score 9):

In a multithreaded environment, it may be mandatory not to use the pyside Slot decorator, because it can cause signals to go to the wrong thread. See

[Derived classes receiving signals in wrong thread in PySide (Qt/PyQt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125065/derived-classes-receiving-signals-in-wrong-thread-in-pyside-qt-pyqt)

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-249

Comment: important detail: they declared a slot in a superclass and then derived from it, which caused issues.